# Javax-RS - how to create a client to push data to a server?

Tags: java, web-services

I need to push data from a standalone client back to the server. This client already accesses the server to get information, parses it, executes what it has to do, but now I need it to push back some information.

I have tried doing this:

```
public class UpdateServer {

    public void update(int resultSetRowCount) {

        AgentConfiguration config = new AgentConfiguration();
        config.init();

        String agentId = AgentConfiguration.agent_id;
        String serverIp = AgentConfiguration.server_ip;
        String serverPort = AgentConfiguration.server_port;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        StringBuilder timestamp = new StringBuilder();

        timestamp.append(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        timestamp.append(String.format("%02d",cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
        timestamp.append(String.format("%02d",cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
        timestamp.append(String.format("%02d",cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)));
        timestamp.append(String.format("%02d",cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
        timestamp.append(String.format("%02d",cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)));

        String date = timestamp.toString();

        String uri = "http://" + serverIp + ":" + serverPort + "/hrm/alerts/" + agentId + "/" + date + "/" + resultSetRowCount;


        System.out.println(uri);

        try {
            // create HTTP Client
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

            // Create new patchRequest with below mentioned URL
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(uri);

            // Add additional header to postRequest which accepts application/xml data
            postRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/xml");

            // Execute your request and catch response
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

            // Check for HTTP response code: 200 = success
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access the server with the formatted uri using:

```
new UpdateServer().update(resultSetRowCount);
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 405
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the causes of http error code 405 is when a payload is not passed to the POST method. Probably that is the case with your program.

You can use `PostMethod` instead of `HttpPost` and set the payload

Your code will look like

```
...
String uri = "http://" + serverIp + ":" + serverPort + "/hrm/alerts/" + agentId + "/" + date + "/" + resultSetRowCount;

System.out.println(uri);

try 
{

   // create HTTP Client
   HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

   PostMethod post = new PostMethod(uri);

   RequestEntity requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(payload, "application/xml", null/*charset default*/);

   post.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);

   int iResult = httpclient.executeMethod(post);

   // get the status code using post.getStatusCode()                
   // you can get the response using post.getResponseBodyAsString()

   // Check for HTTP response code: 200 = success
   if (post.getStatusCode() != 200) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + post.getStatusCode());
   }

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, thanks! But I don't fully understand what you mean by `payload`. Also, on  `int iResult = httpclient.executeMethod(post);` Eclipse marks `executeMethod` as underdefined.

Comment: The payload is the input data which you send while doing a POST or a PUT method.  I am unsure why executeMethod is not working on your side, what is the version of Apache commons library you are using?

Comment: groupId: commons-httpclient, artifactId: commons-httpclient, version: 3.1

Comment: The documentation states the method is available [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpClient.html#executeMethod(org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod))

Comment: I was wondering if I really need a payload. The uri has all the data I need to update on the server. Maybe a GET method would suffice?

Comment: Ok, have you tried calling the web services from the browser or any WS browser app to confirm the working of the web services. In case of you are unaware of any RESTClient app on browser, you can use Postman on chrome

Comment: I think I might be confusing something. This method is to push data (on the uri) to the web server. I don't think I can access it from any browser

Comment: You can, the rest clients are built to access the web services. If you can access it from code, it means, the resource is available over the network and it can be accessed.

Comment: Btw do you have web service's documentation to know the input to web services.

Comment: I may have made a total fool of myself. Apologies. When I said I can't access the above method from a browser, I meant this client is a standalone jar, that accesses the server via an implementation that's already working, but it initiates the request. What I want to do now is the other way around. I want this java desktop application to make a request to the server and that the server decodes the `uri` string and updates some entities there.